# browseVignettes: remove `source` and `R code ` files from output

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, r-usethis

I wrote an HTML vignette for my R package hosted on GitHub. When I open it with `browseVignettes`, it flawlessly opens on the browsers showing this content:

```
Vignettes found by browseVignettes("package_name")
Vignettes in package package_name
package_name file_name - HTML  source  R code
```

clicking on  `HTML`  `source`  `R code` it opens the same file in three different versions.

However, I don't need the source and the R code files to show.

Is there a way to output only the HTML file? As in the following output

```
Vignettes found by browseVignettes("package_name")
Vignettes in package package_name
package_name file_name - HTML
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily drop the source, but you can drop the R code by setting that component to blank.  For example,

```
allfields <- browseVignettes()
noR <- lapply(allfields, function(pkg) {pkg[,"R"] <- ""; pkg})
class(noR) <- class(allfields)
noR
```

If you really want to drop the source, then you'll need to get the print method and modify it:

```
print.browseVignettes <- utils:::print.browseVignettes
# Modify it as you like.
```